# Cannot make a function to be auto-refreshed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I cannot make a function to be auto-refreshed on a set period of time.

I have a test page where I want to simulate auto-refresh for a set period of time. Let's say I have 4 images and I want them to be displayed randomly when the "spot" is auto-refreshed.

This is what I have at the moment:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var imageURLs = [
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/24/Ad-MediumRectangle-300x250.jpg",
            "http://orissadiary.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/advertise-here-300x250.png",
            "https://pics.me.me/medium-rectangle-300px-x-250px-18306117.png",
            "https://travelfree.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/1454913661banner300.gif"
        ];

        function getImageTag() {
            var img = '<img src=\"';
            var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageURLs.length);
            img += imageURLs[randomIndex];
            img += '\" alt=\"Some alt text\"/>';
            return img;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
      <div class="autorefresh">   
          <script type="text/javascript">
              document.write(getImageTag());
              setInterval('getImageTag()', 3000);
          </script>
       </div>

</body>
</html>
```

What I get now, with this code is random image BUT only when I manually refresh the page. Let's say that I don't understand much of HTML CSS JS and I cannot figure out what is wrong. Could anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's solution to add new adds :**

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 
 function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

        var imageURLs = [
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/24/Ad-MediumRectangle-300x250.jpg",
            "http://orissadiary.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/advertise-here-300x250.png",
            "https://pics.me.me/medium-rectangle-300px-x-250px-18306117.png",
            "https://travelfree.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/1454913661banner300.gif"
        ];

        function getImageTag() {
            var img = '<img src=\"';
            var randomIndex = getRandomInt(0, imageURLs.length-1);
            img += imageURLs[randomIndex];
            img += '\" alt=\"Some alt text\"/>';
            return img;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
      <div class="autorefresh">   
          <script type="text/javascript">
             
             
              function update(){
              
                 document.write(getImageTag());
              
              }
              
              setInterval(update, 3000);
              
              
          </script>
       </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Here's solution to update exist Img :**

```js
function update(){

  var myContainer = document.getElementById("autorefresh");
  myContainer.innerHTML = "";
  myContainer.appendChild(getImageTag());

}

setInterval(update, 3000);
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     
     function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        min = Math.ceil(min);
        max = Math.floor(max);
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

            var imageURLs = [
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/24/Ad-MediumRectangle-300x250.jpg",
                "http://orissadiary.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/advertise-here-300x250.png",
                "https://pics.me.me/medium-rectangle-300px-x-250px-18306117.png",
                "https://travelfree.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/1454913661banner300.gif"
            ];

         function getImageTag() {
         
            var img = new Image();
            var randomIndex = getRandomInt(0, imageURLs.length-1);
             img.src = imageURLs[randomIndex];
             img.alt="Some alt text";
            return img;
         }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
          <div id="autorefresh">   
           </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

This is much better than literal and write function :

> var img = new Image();

You need to avoid eval and write this functions can be danger.

https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/

Comment: Thank you very much. This works just fine. I can proceed now :)

Answer (score -1):

Strip the quotation marks on the function and add 'window'.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     getImageTag();
     window.setInterval(getImageTag, 3000);
</script>
```

Also, the code should look more like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         var imageURLs = [
             "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/24/Ad-MediumRectangle-300x250.jpg",
             "http://orissadiary.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/advertise-here-300x250.png",
             "https://pics.me.me/medium-rectangle-300px-x-250px-18306117.png",
             "https://travelfree.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/1454913661banner300.gif"
         ];

        function getImageTag() {
            var img = '<img src=\"';
            var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageURLs.length);
            img += imageURLs[randomIndex];
            img += '\" alt=\"Some alt text\"/>';
            return img;
        }
     </script>
 </head>

     <body>
          <div class="autorefresh">   
              <script type="text/javascript">
                  window.onload = function() {
                      document.write(getImageTag());
                      window.setInterval(getImageTag(), 3000);
                  };
              </script>
          </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not correct : "window.setInterval(getImageTag(), 3000);"

Comment: Just try it : function getI(){
console.log("not work")
}
window.setInterval(getI(), 3000);

Comment: Because the () causes the function to be executed there and then when you declare the timer, and then the timer tries to execute the _result_ of the function when the time expires. If you want to pass a _reference_ to the function then remove the (). P.s. if this needs to repeat infinitely (as seems likely from the question) then use an interval not a timeout

Comment: Also you forgot to make the getImageTag function actually output anything into the page.

Comment: There, I fixed it.